# Optimum solution using for loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, count

I have a list

```
items=["apple","carrot","bike","dog"]
```

The result I want

```
ordered_items = {"fruit": items[0],"vegetable":items[1],"vehicle":items[2],"animal":items[3]}
```

print(ordered_items)

```
{
"fruit": "apple","vegetable":"carrot","vehicle":"bike","animal":"dog"
}
```

Here I have to explicitly mention the index from the list(items) in the resultant dictionary(ordered_items) which is definitely not the right approach when the list(items) gets updated in the future.

Is there any alternative way I can form in key-value pair by using for-loop/count or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize a `dict` straight from the output of `zip` like this:

```py
items = ["apple", "carrot", "bike", "dog"]
categories = ["fruit", "vegetable", "vehicle", "animal"]

dict(zip(categories, items))

>>> {'fruit': 'apple', 'vegetable': 'carrot', 'vehicle': 'bike', 'animal': 'dog'}
```

### Explanation

A `dict` can be instantiated in [different ways](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), one of which is *sequence of key-value pairs*:

```py
dict([("foo", 5), ("bar", 2)])
>>> {'foo': 5, 'bar': 2}
```

`zip(*iterables)` creates a `zip` object which yields tuples when iterated. In our case where we gave it *two* iterables (categories and items) it will yield tuple *pairs*, which is perfect for our use case:

```py
list(zip(["foo", "bar"], [5, 2]))
>>> [('foo', 5), ('bar', 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be done using dictionary comprehension:

```
items = ["apple", "carrot", "bike", "dog"]
categories = ["fruit", "vegetable", "vehicle", "animal"]

{c: i for c, i in zip(categories, items)}
```

Output:

```
{'fruit': 'apple', 'vegetable': 'carrot', 'vehicle': 'bike', 'animal': 'dog'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip()` function and then convert it to dictionary.

```
items=["apple","carrot","bike","dog"]
keys = ["fruit", "vegetable","vehicle","animal"]
ordered_items = dict(zip(keys, items))

print(ordered_items)
```